# tail -f command and null copy doesn't work well

Tags: unix

Why tail command -f option does not work well. when target file was null clear, then tail command does not write out anymote.

```
tail -f hoge&
cp /dev/null  hoge
```

Comment: Why do you invoke tail command in the background? (& at the end)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tail also has a `tail -F` option which checks to see if the file has been changed.

From the man page:

> The -F option implies the -f option, but tail will also check to see
>   if the file being followed has been renamed or rotated.  The file is
>   closed and reopened when tail detects that the filename being read
>   from has a new inode number.  The -F option is ignored if reading from
>   standard input rather than a file.